# Java package organization and access modifier

Tags: java, eclipse, package, internal

So I am struggling with the organization of my classes and packages. I have a lot of classes, so i am currently sorting them to corresponding packages. 
Now i have the following situation with 2 classes:

One with a 'not public' constructor:

```
package example;
public class File { 
    File() { // constructor should not be public 
    }   
    // stuff...
}
```

and one using the other ones constructor:

```
package example.specialfiles;
import example.File;
public class CatalogFile {
    private File wrappedFile;   
    CatalogFile() {
        wrappedFile = new File();
    }   
    // stuff...
}
```

which looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YNeN.png) in eclipse.

Obviously the File-constructor can not be called inside CatalogFile, because it is located in another package.

Since there is no c#-like `internal` the only working solution i can think of is putting them both into the same package, which breaks the purpose of packages in my opinion.

Is there any other solution or a workaround to organize the classes inside Eclipse independent of the package structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want others to instantiate your File (choose better name), you should place in the same package. Yes, it can be messy, true, but easy.

If you want to hide your constructor from others, you can make a getInstance() method what creates your object for you (Factory method pattern), and in the method you can check if caller has access to create or not. For example with Java Reflection API.